# How to use private action method in .net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can i use private action method in controller? when i used private method it is not accessible. it throws error as "resource not found".

```
private ActionResult Index()
                {
                    return View();
                }
```

Comment: what would be the purpose of making an `ActionResult` private?

Comment: I just wanna know that is there any possible for that

Comment: @AndrewCounts 's question is valid. I want to know many things, but why _should_ I?

Comment: An `ActionResult` exists explicitly for the purpose of returning a result to the framework; It would make absolutely no sense for it to be private... What else would it be needed for?

Comment: Just try returning the private action from a public one and see what happens: `public ActionResult MyPublicAction(){return Index();}`. by the way, all the questions above are perfectly solid.

Comment: Well, theoretically one can use a private method that returns an `ActionResult` and use it from public controller actions to, say, prevent code duplication.

Comment: An example of a good use for this: Trying to redirect from within a `Controller` to a public `ActionResult` that uses `[HttpPost][ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` can be tricky.  Having a shared internal call can make that less cumbersome. Very similar to the `[ChildActionOnly] of past...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a private/protected `ActionResult` to share logic between public actions.

```
private ActionResult SharedActionLogic( int foo ){
    return new EmptyResult();
}

public ActionResult PublicAction1(){
    return SharedActionLogic( 1 );
}

public ActionResult PublicAction2(){
    return SharedActionLogic( 2 );
}
```

But only public action methods will ever be invoked by the framework (see source below). This is by design.

From the internal class ActionMethodSelector in System.Web.Mvc:

```
private void PopulateLookupTables()
{
    // find potential matches from public, instance methods
    MethodInfo[] allMethods = ControllerType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

    // refine further if needed
    MethodInfo[] actionMethods = Array.FindAll(allMethods, IsValidActionMethod);

    // remainder of method omitted
}
```

It is common to have non-public code in a controller, and automatically routing all methods would violate expected behavior and increase attack footprint.